# XDocument Namespace on root and first child

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces

I'm building an xml file using XDocument

```
XDocument single = new XDocument(
                new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "true"),
                new XElement(_namespace + "vcards",
                    XElement.Parse(BuildCardEntry(contact))));
```

Inside `BuildCardEntry(contact)` I'm adding the namespace to every `XElement` too.
But my code pruduces this

```
<vcards xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:vcard-3.0">
  <vcard xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:vcard-3.0">
```

insted of this

```
<vcards xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:vcard-3.0">
  <vcard>
```

Does somebody know, how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SaveOptions.OmitDuplicateNamespaces` parameter when saving xml.

```
single.Save(..., SaveOptions.OmitDuplicateNamespaces);
```